# Mysql replication Ignore specific table

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

I want to exclude some table for replication in slave db. How i can do it. what steps needs to be implement on master server or slave server?
I dont want anymore some tables in slave server. is there any way to add wild card in my.cnf file or any query which i have to use to stop it.

Comment: Refer to the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

- On Primary: binlog_... prevents sending updates for specified *databases* to Replicas.
- On Replica: replicate_ignore_table_... ignores updates for specified *tables*
- The tables that are already on the Replica are not DROPped; you must do that manually (on the Replica).

The settings changes should go into `my.cnf`; such changes won't take effect until you restart the server.